# How to get the index of the row onClick of a button?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to get the row index when I click on the button of a row in datatable but instead of getting the real index I am getting the displayed index. This is happening when I add a new row and then click on the button of that row. The order of the table is by a timestamp so the new row goes immediately to top therefor when I click on the button it gives me index 0 but that's just the displayed table index, not the real index.

```
function myFunction(this_) {
  var tr = $(this_).closest("tr");
  rowindex = tr.index();  //this gives the displayed index of the row, NOT the real index
}
```

Calling this function from html datatable button:

```
<td>
  <button type="button" id="edit_button" onclick='myFunction(this)' name="edit_button">Edit</button>
</td>
```

UPDATE:
I have tried to print the index of all rows when I add a new row:

```
   table.rows().every( function () {
     console.log(this.index());
  });
```

and it gives the correct indexes so it prints like this:

5
2
3
4

as you can see the index 5 is the first because due to the order/filtering I am using it is displayed in the first row.

**Simply put, instead of giving me index 5 it is giving 0 when I click on the first row's button.**

Comment: What do you mean by 'displayed index' and 'real index'? The index returned will be based on the number of `tr` elements in the containing `tbody`, regardless of whether they are displayed or not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the displayed index from what I have heard is the index of the rows as they are displayed, so depending on the sorting or filtering the first row might have index 7 but it will give 0 because it is displayed as the first row in the table. This is exactly the problem I am having.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting what you mean. If the row is displayed first in the table then it will always be index 0. Why do you believe it would be index 7 in your example?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see the updated question, maybe it clarifies a little bit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe its not even an index just row number, so sorry if I am using the wrong syntax here. So, instead of calling 'displayed index' I should call it row number.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan did you read it?

Comment: I did read it, but it still made no sense.

Answer (score 0):

On the tr element, just add an attribute like "id" or any name, to set your row number. so you can manipulate the row.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonData = [ 
    { "Id": "1", "Name": "Tiger Nixon", "Position": "System Architect", "Office": "Edinburgh", "Age": 61 },
  { "Id": "2", "Name": "Garrett Winters", "Position": "Accountant", "Office": "Tokyo", "Age": 63 },
  { "Id": "3", "Name": "Ashton Cox", "Position": "Jr. Technical Author", "Office": "San Francisco", "Age": 66 },
  { "Id": "4", "Name": "Cedric Kelly", "Position": "Sr. Javascript Developer", "Office": "Edinburgh", "Age": 22 },
  { "Id": "5", "Name": "Airi Satou", "Position": "Accountant", "Office": "Tokyo", "Age": 33 },
  { "Id": "6", "Name": "Brielle Williamson", "Position": "Integration Specialist", "Office": "New York", "Age": 61 },
  { "Id": "7", "Name": "Herrod Chandler", "Position": "Sales Assistant", "Office": "San Francisco", "Age": 59 },
  { "Id": "8", "Name": "Rhona Davidson", "Position": "Integration Specialist", "Office": "Tokyo", "Age": 55 },
  { "Id": "9", "Name": "Colleen Hurst", "Position": "Javascript Developer", "Office": "San Francisco", "Age": 39 },
  { "Id": "10", "Name": "Sonya Frost", "Position": "Software Engineer", "Office": "Edinburgh", "Age": 23 } ];

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  LengthChange: false,
  data: jsonData,
  columns: [
      { data: 'Id' },
      { data: 'Name' },
      { data: 'Position' },
      { data: 'Office' },
      { data: 'Age' },
      { 
        data: null,
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
           return '<button onClick="showIndex(' + meta.row + ')">Click me</button>';
        }
      },
    ]
});

function showIndex(index) {
        alert(index);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Remember, if you click the button of the row with Id 1 and you get a 0 (zero), is because internally for jQuery DataTable the first row index is 0 not 1 (same as in an array)